# Create audio timestamps on a bicycle

Tags: audio-editing

I want to edit out mistakes from a 2 hour podcast episode but this would take hours of time that I don't have. On the other hand I spend around an hour a day driving my bicycle through safe forest roads and I want to use that time productively to create the timestamps in the audio file so that I can later just quickly jump to the few timestamps and edit the previously identified mistakes in Audacity.

Is there a software / system that allows me to listen to the podcast on my bike while somehow letting me input the timestamps without using my hands?

My ideas are:

1. using some kind of mouth device that I can trigger with my tongue to mark a timestamp
2. using voice commands with an external microphone such as "timestamp"

But I'm open for other input methods as long as they don't impact me driving safely.

Comment: This site is for software recommendations, so you should better ask for an iOS or android app that plays the audio file and records your timestamps (e.g. using a Bluetooth based push button mounted to the bicycle's handlebar.

Comment: I would recommend against doing this. Whilst cycling, you need to be fully aware of your surroundings. If you're having to listen to a recording and press a button to mark a timestamp, you're not focussing on where you're going.